# TFS2010 - Sync with apache web server - Working folder

Tags: synchronization, working-directory

I am working on Team Foundation Server 2010 and need to set a working folder to my project but i can't find that choice on right click menu as usual (set mapping folder). do i have to define a build or something ?

in fact, all what i need to do is :

I am running a web project on apache httpd server and for make easy to the team to edit and update files at the same time i decided to use TFS2010.

now all of us could update files on TFS successfully but the thing is i have to find a way to download these updates again to apache automatically when check in.

So, is setting working folder the only way to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to update your Apache files on checkin, a working folder won't work as it wouldn't update automatically, you would have to 'get latest' manually.

I think you are right in that creating a build definition is the way to go as it can be triggered by a checkin and you can then do more or less anything you want with the code and build output. The workflow stuff does have a bit of a learning curve, but as you can execute scripts from the workflow it makes it a bit easier, or you could use the legacy build template and a MSBuild project.

Comment: Thank you. would you please guide me to any tutorial explain this clearly ? I am new in TFS stuff.

Comment: Would you prefer to go with a MSBuild or Workflow solution?

Comment: the easier. so i guess i will go with workflow. Thank you so much